# How should I structure my products

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a computer product that fits many types of computers.  The product has a brand, and more than one computer model can use the same product.  I want to let users search by product, or click through by brand, or click through by product.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set this up with Drupal Commerce.  I read up and down on the site, but can't seem to get it.

One brand to many products.
One product to many computer types.
One computer type to many products.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brands are clearly taxonomies.
The other two are two product types.
With the help of [Commerce Search API](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api) you can easily have facets on brands, as well as powerful search.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding "product type".  Are you saying the computer that uses the product is a type, and the product is a product type?

Comment: That put me in the right direction.  Brands for taxonomies, the computers are content types, and the products are product types and displays.  I'm setting an entity reference from the computer to the product display, and can use Views EVA to group them together.